# I am trying to check if system password entered is correct or not using bash script, using subprocess()

Tags: python-3.x, bash

I am making a program where user enters system password and I check it.

I am using `subprocess()` to pass password to a random install command in bash and trying to get grab output using check_output and check that against some value but unable to do so.

Here is what I have tried

```
import os

import subprocess

def mainFunction(password):

    commandToRunRouter="echo " +password + " | sudo -S  install  something"
    answer=subprocess.check_output(commandToRunRouter,shell=True)
    print("result")
    print(answer)
    if answer!=0:
        return False
    return True
```

Answer variable should store value `'Sorry wrong password.'` which is what is displayed when you enter wrong password but it is storing some random variables.

What am I doing wrong??

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) for `check_output`:

> If the return code was non-zero it raises a CalledProcessError. The CalledProcessError object will have the return code in the returncode attribute and any output in the output attribute.

That means you have to catch the exception and readout the output from there. Also make sure to capture `stdout` and `stderr`. Something like this might work for you:

```py
import os

import subprocess

def mainFunction(password):

    commandToRunRouter="echo " +password + " | sudo -S  install  something"
    try:
        answer=subprocess.check_output(commandToRunRouter,shell=True, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as cpe:
        print(cpe.returncode)
        print(cpe.output)
        return False
    return True
```

Also consider not passing the password over a pipe as that might be a security issue.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reply but i found one more way to do that using subporcess.call(), I am posting my answer below for use of others-

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import subprocess

def start(password):
    commandToRunRouter="echo " +password + " | sudo -S  apt update" 
    answer=subprocess.call(commandToRunRouter,shell=True)
    if answer==0:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```